# In Laravel, how to set multiple hasMany (1 to many) relationships on the same record simultaneously?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm making an appointment app, a user can create an appointment at a certain date and time with another user. I have a users table and an appointments table. Each appointment has an initiator ID (the user who suggested the appointment) and a recipient ID (the user who receives the appointment request), and the models have hasMany relationships (code below)

My question is, when I create an appointment, how do I get Eloquent to associate BOTH the initiator AND the recipient with the new appointment. Looking at the syntax in the docs, I can easily do e.g. just the initiator, like so:

```
$initiator = User::find(Auth::user()->id); // Get user from DB who is the initiator
$appt = $initiator->appts_initiator()->create(['address' => $request->input('address'), 'whendatetime' => $request->input('whendatetime')]);
```

or I could do just the recipient:

```
$recipient = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first(); // Get recipient user
$appt = $recipient->appts_recipient()->create(['address' => $request->input('address'), 'whendatetime' => $request->input('whendatetime')]);
```

During that line with create() in it, I need to get Eloquent to associate both initiator and recipient. Or do I have to manually inject the correct ID as one of the parameters in the create(), which would seem to bypass the point of Eloquent!

Relevant model code:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    // Get all of the user's appointments where they are an initiator:
    public function appts_initiator()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment', 'initiator_id');
        }

    // Get all of the user's appointments where they are a recipient:
    public function appts_recipient()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment', 'recipient_id');
        }
}

class Appointment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('whendatetime', 'address', 'minuteslate');

    // Get user who is the initiator for this appointment:
    public function initiator_user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'initiator_id');
        }

    // Get user who is the recipient for this appointment:
    public function recipient_user()
        {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'recipient_id');
        }

    // Get the payment for this appointment:
    public function get_payment()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Payment'); // Default foreign key (appointment_id)
        }
}
```

Relevant bit of user table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password');
```

and appointments table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('initiator_id')->unsigned(); // User who initiated to appointment
$table->integer('recipient_id')->unsigned(); // User who receives the appointment request
$table->dateTime('whendatetime'); // Date and time of appointment
$table->string('address'); // Address of the appointment
```

Thanks for any suggestions.
Alex

Comment: create() returns the created model, so you can chain onto it but I don't see the point in this scenario. Why would adding the id be avoiding the point of eloquent? How else would your query know which record of the other table it relates to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$initiator = Auth::user();
$recipient = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
$appt = new Appointment();
$appt->address = $request->input('address'); 
$appt->whendatetime = $request->input('whendatetime');
$appt->initiator_user()->associate($initiator);
$appt->recipient_user()->associate($recipient);
$appt->save();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do that all in one hit, in 1 line, e.g. using create()?